# How can I align svg circle in the middle of the div?

Tags: html, css, svg, centering

I need to make a circle emulating the button for closing the window in the Mac OS. But when I try to move it lower, svg's border cuts it off. How can I move the border to place the circle directly in the middle of the panel (vertically)?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sm6r0kvn/2/

```html
<div class="panel">
  <svg viewbox="0 0 20 17" width="20" heigth="50"><circle r="7" cx="14" cy="9.5" fill="#fc615e"/></svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Your `viewbox `looks wrong and the `cx/cy` values - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/VNZKoL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set your *viewbox* like `<svg viewbox="0 0 20 20" width="20" heigth="20">` and then set `cx` and `cy` 50%. If you want to center it in the `panel` vertically just make it a flexbox and add `align-items: center` - see demo below:

```css
.block {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  max-width: 550px;
  min-width: 480px;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 200px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 5px 5px;
}

.panel {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  display: flex; /* added */
  align-items: center; /* added */
}

.text {
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="panel">
    <svg viewbox="0 0 20 20" width="20" heigth="20">
      <circle r="7" cx="50%" cy="50%" fill="#fc615e"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    Text here
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are drawing your cicrcle outside of the svg viewbox. You can either use CSS to move whole svg box or make it larger

```css
svg {
  border: 1px blue solid;
}
.panel.moved {
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <svg viewbox="0 0 20 20" width="200" heigth="200">
    <circle r="10" cx="10" cy="10" fill="#fc615e"/>
  </svg>
</div>
<div class="panel">
  <svg viewbox="0 0 20 20" width="200" heigth="200">
    <circle r="10" cx="20" cy="10" fill="#fc615e"/>
  </svg>
</div>
<div class="panel">
  <svg viewbox="0 0 30 20" width="300" heigth="200">
    <circle r="10" cx="20" cy="10" fill="#fc615e"/>
  </svg>
</div>
<div class="panel moved">
  <svg viewbox="0 0 20 20" width="200" heigth="200">
    <circle r="10" cx="10" cy="10" fill="#fc615e"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```